# webpack + TypeScript = all files checked instead of a single file

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'd like to transpile `index.ts` with **webpack**, but it also checks `another.ts` while there is no dependency. Why ?

Demo :

```
$ node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

[...]

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:3
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:6
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:33
    TS1002: Unterminated string literal.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:1
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'I'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:3
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'don'.
```

Full demo :

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
$ sudo yum install epel-release
$ sudo yum install nodejs
$ node -v
v6.10.3
$ npm init
$ npm install --save-dev typescript ts-loader webpack
$ node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -v
Version 2.3.4
$ node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc --init
$ vim index.ts
```

`index.ts` :

```
class Person {
    public name: string;

    constructor(name:string) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

let p:Person = new Person("Joe");
console.log(p.name);
```

Transpilation works :

```
$ node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc index.ts
```

Execution works :

```
$ node index.js
Joe
```

**Webpack** configuration :

```
$ node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js -v
3.0.0
$ vim webpack.config.js
```

`webpack.config.js` :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: __dirname
  }
};
```

Transpilation works :

```
$ node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

Execution works :

```
$ node bundle.js
Joe
```

Another file creation :

```
$ vim another.ts
```

`another.ts` :

```
I don't want to check this file.
```

Re-transpilation :

```
$ node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

**ERRORS !**

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:3
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:6
    TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:33
    TS1002: Unterminated string literal.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:1
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'I'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./another.ts:1:3
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'don'.
```

`another.ts` is checked while it's not in `webpack.config.js` ! Why !

I tried with `awesome-typescript-loader` instead of `ts-loader`, same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awesome-typescript-loader load / compile only refrenced files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234525/awesome-typescript-loader-load-compile-only-refrenced-files)

Comment: Indeed, setting `files` to `[]` in `tsconfig.json` solves the problem, thanks.