# Webpack - cannot exclude directory

Tags: webpack

I cannot exclude a directory, web pack regex dont make any sens

I have a folder called "ignore", so I tried /ignore/, /^ignore/ /ignore(.+)?$/ and many more

it does not help, webpack always takes the directory with the rest of the project
this is driving me nuts, I already checked on many other forums, the given solutions either do not work , or simply do not make any sens

```
  config.module = {
        rules: [
            // Support for .ts files.
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader?' + atlOptions, 'angular2-template-loader', '@angularclass/hmr-loader'],
                exclude: [isTest ? /\.(e2e)\.ts$/ : /\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/, /node_modules\/(?!(ng2-.+))/, /ignore(.+)?$/]
            },
```

It shoudl be so simple, can someone help me out on this ?

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [awesome-typescript-loader load / compile only refrenced files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234525/awesome-typescript-loader-load-compile-only-refrenced-files)

Comment: damned I tried so many thing, this seems to work, thanks