# Webpack 2 won't compile a single typescript file

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, compilation, webpack-2

I'm on a project where I have multiple SPA on Angular JS, all written in typescript. I have the following directory structure:

```
src/
├── app
│   ├── frontend
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── frontend.module.ts
│   ├── backend
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── backend.module.ts
├── app.frontend.module.ts
├── app.backend.module.ts
```

Files at the root of **src/** are the entry point for each app, they contain the following code (here for the frontend):

```js
import * as angular from "angular";
import { FrontendModuleName } from './app/frontend/frontend.module';

angular.module('app', [FrontendModuleName]);
angular.bootstrap(document, ['app'], {
    strictDi: true
});
```

So I should be able to tell Webpack to compile "**src/app.frontend.module.ts**", the compiler then follows the imports and everything gets merged nicely.

It works fine, but even if I explicitly tell Webpack to compile a **single** file, **all** of them are always compiled.

To give you an example, let's take this very basic configuration:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    entry: {
        frontend: './app.frontend.module.ts',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders:  [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                loaders: ['ts-loader']
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Executing this will compile **app.frontend.module.ts** as requested BUT also **app.backend.module.ts** !

After some time I found out that it's not Webpack but the Typescript compiler who seems at fault, so I changed my `.tsconfig` to try to exclude the root files, like so :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "dev",
    "reports",
    "./src/app.*.module.ts"
  ]
}
```

In a sense it works because it now ignores **app.backend.module.ts**, but it still tries to compile every **.ts** file in the **src/app/backend/** directory!

That's where I am right now.. I've searched in the [compiler options reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) but didn't found any option to prevent the compiler to recursively compile everything.

**In fact..**

..I've found a very very ugly workaround that I don't find satisfying at all. There is the `files` options that can be used to specify what files should be compiled, but I cannot give it an empty array or an exception is thrown.

So I created an empty `dummy.ts` file in the `src/` folder and it seems to work as expected:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      ...
  },
  "files": ["src/dummy.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "dev",
    "reports",
    "./src/app.*.module.ts"
  ]
}
```

But I can't imagine there is no better way to handle this.

Any idea would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The empty files array does not seem to be allowed by `tsc` and `ts-loader` is not willing to alter that behaviour (as discussed in the [GitHub issue #405](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader/issues/405)). You could use [`awesome-typescript-loader`](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader) instead, which does allow the empty files array. Technically you should put the entry point(s) in `files` as shown in [awesome-typescript-loader load / compile only refrenced files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234525/awesome-typescript-loader-load-compile-only-refrenced-files/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Indeed, it works great with awesome-typescript-loader, I didn't try it. I still have to set the "files" options to an empty array because I want the ability to only compile one app at a time, so I cannot statically list the entry points in tsconfig. Anyway, thanks for your help.